# Reputation changes point icon doesn't cover recent achievements sign

Tags: discussion, design, stack-exchange

I notice today one thing in design.

*If you scale in chrome to 120%* (Standard font too small for me)

[image]

If we look closer:

[image]

My inner perfectionalist crying with blood. Can we increase height or font size? Something like that:

[image]

But could it be by design?

Comment: Please keep the white color.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeap, it's my bad i mean only height of ico or font size

Comment: _waiting for an upvote to reproduce..._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  _waiting for upvote to make screeanshot with white color font..._

Comment: Huh, well it looks like I had one [and I can't reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KkwA4.png)... =/ (latest Firefox on Windows 10)

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: =) A bit. Windows 8.1 Chrome wide screen. @Will

Comment: [No repo here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/haf7v.png)  Win7, Chrome v49

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ hm, could be that it's my side bug...

Comment: @Tunaki  FYI, you can always inspect the Achievements button and just show the unread count span and toss in a value. That's what I did.. I'm not cool enough to catch +50 at once.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ now i get it. It reproduces only on http://stackoverflow.com/. But not on meta

Comment: @teovankot Still no repo - http://i.stack.imgur.com/dVjQY.png

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Not enough rep. It starts to act bizarre [when the number gets big](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw5JZ.png) though. :D

Comment: @Tunaki  Yeah, but, what's they likelihood of someone getting 1mil rep between visits? Unless we're talking Jon Skeet..then it should just show an infinity symbol..

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ finnaly find out why i'm getting this bug - it's becouse of scale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we can expect SE to display properly for *all* resolutions, on *all* browsers, at *all* zoom levels.

Although zooming in browsers has improved over the years, it's still relatively unpredictable, as is evident from this report.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen comments from SE devs in past that they don't support none-default zoom levels.